# How to update only rows selected in SYS_REFCURSOR

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I want to update only the rows selected in a cursor inside a procedure and return that cursor. My procedure is below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_FETCH_TEST
(OUT_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS 
BEGIN

  OPEN OUT_CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT UNIQUE_ID , COMMENTS , STATUS FROM T_TEST WHERE STATUS=0

END P_FETCH_TEST;
```

I want to add some code in the procedure to update the status column of those rows which are selected in cursor `OUT_CURSOR`.

In short, I want to update rows fetched by the cursor `OUT_CURSOR`.

Comment: Look at "select ... for update"

Comment: you can directly write the update statement before opening the cursor

Comment: Any luck with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have updated the comments column in the following.Change whatever you want for yourself.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_FETCH_TEST
(OUT_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS 
BEGIN

UPDATE T_TEST SET COMMENTS='your_value' WHERE STATUS=0;

OPEN OUT_CURSOR FOR 
SELECT UNIQUE_ID , COMMENTS , STATUS FROM T_TEST WHERE STATUS=0

END P_FETCH_TEST;
```